# How to change the no of columns in different rows in Gridview

Tags: android, grid

I am working in an app which requires a grid view with 2 columns. I want to show only one picture in 1st column and then two pictures in all the other columns.

my grid view:

```
    <GridView


    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dip"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dip" />
```

my current view 
![enter image description here][1]

and view i want

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to put that one image in GridView Header, because this kind of stuff will occurs some problems in development and it will become complex. So put that one image in header and remaining are in gridview. Everything will work fine. See header example below:

```
private View headerView;

headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR HEADER LAYOUT, null, false);//YOUR HEADER LAYOUT is a xml file with the content which you need to display in header, in your case its ImageView only.

ImageView imageview;
imageview = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR IMAGEVIEW NAME);

gridview.addView(headerView);
gridview.setAdapter(YOUR ADAPTER);
```

Comment: Thank you @pratik for your answer. But how to put image in Gridview Header?

Comment: thanks for the such a nice answer but there is another thing i want to ask as you see in my above pics there is two icons of email and phone if i add image in Grid view header than that icon will work or not on click ??

Comment: whatever you want just put that in your header xml. behave just like your main xml, design whatever you like. You can see different in code when you do findViewById, its from header. Remaining all the things will work perfectly, but that 2 click events you need to create it different from gridview, you can not put it in adapter.

Comment: when i add this method gridview.addHeaderView(headerView); then is shows error like method is not found.

Comment: Check my edited answer and try with it. Or read some document related this method, you will find it surely.